# AES decryption in PHP

Tags: php, actionscript, aes

I have a base64 encrypted string that I need to decrypt using PHP, the encrypted string was generated by a flash application I reversed and I found it uses AES. The problem is that I don't know if the AES implementation I got is a standard I can replicate in PHP. It would be better if there is a PHP class I can use without installing mcrypt.
Here is an example of what the flash application does to decrypt the string:

```
var encrypted:String = AES.encrypt("hello world","my great key",AES.BIT_KEY_256); // "06/0/6Ojo6ObeIEZaHcxAinbjD=="
// I need to do this in php
var decrypted:String = AES.decrypt("06/0/6Ojo6ObeIEZaHcxAinbjD==","my great key",AES.BIT_KEY_256); // "hello world"
```

The reversed AES class:

```
public class AES {

    public static const BIT_KEY_128:int = 128;
    public static const BIT_KEY_192:int = 192;
    public static const BIT_KEY_256:int = 0x0100;
    private static const SBOX:Array = [
        99, 124, 119, 123, 242, 107, 111, 197, 48, 1, 103, 43, 254, 215, 171, 118, 202, 130, 201, 125, 250, 89, 71, 240, 173, 212, 162, 175, 156, 164, 114, 192, 183, 253, 147, 38, 54, 63, 247, 204, 52, 165, 229, 241, 113, 216, 49, 21, 4, 199, 35, 195, 24, 150, 5, 154, 7, 18, 128, 226, 235, 39, 178, 117, 9, 131, 44, 26, 27, 110, 90, 160, 82, 59, 214, 179, 41, 227, 47, 132, 83, 209, 0, 237, 32, 252, 177, 91, 106, 203, 190, 57, 74, 76, 88, 207, 208, 239, 170, 251, 67, 77, 51, 133, 69, 249, 2, 127, 80, 60, 159, 168, 81, 163, 64, 143, 146, 157, 56, 245, 188, 182, 218, 33, 16, 0xFF, 243, 210, 205, 12, 19, 236, 95, 151, 68, 23, 196, 167, 126, 61, 100, 93, 25, 115, 96, 129, 79, 220, 34, 42, 144, 136, 70, 238, 184, 20, 222, 94, 11, 219, 224, 50, 58, 10, 73, 6, 36, 92, 194, 211, 172, 98, 145, 149, 228, 121, 231, 200, 55, 109, 141, 213, 78, 169, 108, 86, 244, 234, 101, 122, 174, 8, 186, 120, 37, 46, 28, 166, 180, 198, 232, 221, 116, 31, 75, 189, 139, 138, 112, 62, 181, 102, 72, 3, 246, 14, 97, 53, 87, 185, 134, 193, 29, 158, 225, 248, 152, 17, 105, 217, 142, 148, 155, 30, 135, 233, 206, 85, 40, 223, 140, 161, 137, 13, 191, 230, 66, 104, 65, 153, 45, 15, 176, 84, 187, 22];
    private static const RCON:Array = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 0, 0, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0],
        [16, 0, 0, 0],
        [32, 0, 0, 0],
        [64, 0, 0, 0],
        [128, 0, 0, 0],
        [27, 0, 0, 0],
        [54, 0, 0, 0]
    ];

    public static function encrypt(_arg1:String, _arg2:String, _arg3:int):String {
        var _local19:int;
        var _local20:Array;
        var _local21:int;
        var _local22:Array;
        var _local4 = 16;
        if (!(((((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_128)) || ((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_192)))) || ((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_256)))) {
            throw (new Error("Must be a key mode of either 128, 192, 256 bits"));
        }
        ;
        _arg1 = Utf8.encode(_arg1);
        _arg2 = Utf8.encode(_arg2);
        var _local5:int = (_arg3 / 8);
        var _local6:Array = new Array(_local5);
        var _local7:int;
        while (_local7 < _local5) {
            _local6[_local7] = ((isNaN(_arg2.charCodeAt(_local7))) ? 0 : _arg2.charCodeAt(_local7));
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        var _local8:Array = cipher(_local6, keyExpansion(_local6));
        _local8 = cipher(_local6, keyExpansion(_local6)).concat(_local8.slice(0, (_local5 - 16)));
        var _local9:Array = new Array(_local4);
        var _local10:int = new Date().getTime();
        var _local11:int = Math.floor((_local10 / 1000));
        var _local12:int = (_local10 % 1000);
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < 4) {
            _local9[_local7] = ((_local11 >>> (_local7 * 8)) & 0xFF);
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < 4) {
            _local9[(_local7 + 4)] = (_local12 & 0xFF);
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        var _local13 = "";
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < 8) {
            _local13 = (_local13 + String.fromCharCode(_local9[_local7]));
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        var _local14:Array = keyExpansion(_local8);
        var _local15:int = Math.ceil((_arg1.length / _local4));
        var _local16:Array = new Array(_local15);
        var _local17:int;
        while (_local17 < _local15) {
            _local19 = 0;
            while (_local19 < 4) {
                _local9[(15 - _local19)] = ((_local17 >>> (_local19 * 8)) & 0xFF);
                _local19++;
            }
            ;
            _local19 = 0;
            while (_local19 < 4) {
                _local9[((15 - _local19) - 4)] = ((_local17 / 4294967296) >>> (_local19 * 8));
                _local19++;
            }
            ;
            _local20 = cipher(_local9, _local14);
            _local21 = (((_local17 < (_local15 - 1))) ? _local4 : (((_arg1.length - 1) % _local4) + 1));
            _local22 = new Array(_local21);
            _local7 = 0;
            while (_local7 < _local21) {
                _local22[_local7] = (_local20[_local7] ^ _arg1.charCodeAt(((_local17 * _local4) + _local7)));
                _local22[_local7] = String.fromCharCode(_local22[_local7]);
                _local7++;
            }
            ;
            _local16[_local17] = _local22.join("");
            _local17++;
        }
        ;
        var _local18:String = (_local13 + _local16.join(""));
        _local18 = Base64.encode(_local18);
        return (_local18);
    }

    public static function decrypt(_arg1:String, _arg2:String, _arg3:int):String {
        var _local16:int;
        var _local18:int;
        var _local19:Array;
        var _local20:Array;
        var _local4 = 16;
        if (!(((((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_128)) || ((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_192)))) || ((_arg3 == BIT_KEY_256)))) {
            throw (new Error("Must be a key mode of either 128, 192, 256 bits"));
        }
        ;
        _arg1 = Base64.decode(_arg1);
        _arg2 = Utf8.encode(_arg2);
        var _local5:int = (_arg3 / 8);
        var _local6:Array = new Array(_local5);
        var _local7:int;
        while (_local7 < _local5) {
            _local6[_local7] = ((isNaN(_arg2.charCodeAt(_local7))) ? 0 : _arg2.charCodeAt(_local7));
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        var _local8:Array = cipher(_local6, keyExpansion(_local6));
        _local8 = cipher(_local6, keyExpansion(_local6)).concat(_local8.slice(0, (_local5 - 16)));
        var _local9:Array = new Array(8);
        var _local10:String = _arg1.slice(0, 8);
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < 8) {
            _local9[_local7] = _local10.charCodeAt(_local7);
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        var _local11:Array = keyExpansion(_local8);
        var _local12:int = Math.ceil(((_arg1.length - 8) / _local4));
        var _local13:Array = new Array(_local12);
        _local16 = 0;
        while (_local16 < _local12) {
            _local13[_local16] = _arg1.slice((8 + (_local16 * _local4)), ((8 + (_local16 * _local4)) + _local4));
            _local16++;
        }
        ;
        var _local14:Array = _local13;
        var _local15:Array = new Array(_local14.length);
        _local16 = 0;
        while (_local16 < _local12) {
            _local18 = 0;
            while (_local18 < 4) {
                _local9[(15 - _local18)] = ((_local16 >>> (_local18 * 8)) & 0xFF);
                _local18++;
            }
            ;
            _local18 = 0;
            while (_local18 < 4) {
                _local9[((15 - _local18) - 4)] = (((((_local16 + 1) / 4294967296) - 1) >>> (_local18 * 8)) & 0xFF);
                _local18++;
            }
            ;
            _local19 = cipher(_local9, _local11);
            _local20 = new Array(String(_local14[_local16]).length);
            _local7 = 0;
            while (_local7 < String(_local14[_local16]).length) {
                _local20[_local7] = (_local19[_local7] ^ String(_local14[_local16]).charCodeAt(_local7));
                _local20[_local7] = String.fromCharCode(_local20[_local7]);
                _local7++;
            }
            ;
            _local15[_local16] = _local20.join("");
            _local16++;
        }
        ;
        var _local17:String = _local15.join("");
        _local17 = Utf8.decode(_local17);
        return (_local17);
    }

    private static function cipher(_arg1:Array, _arg2:Array):Array {
        var _local3 = 4;
        var _local4:int = ((_arg2.length / _local3) - 1);
        var _local5:Array = [
            [],
            [],
            [],
            []
        ];
        var _local6:int;
        while (_local6 < (4 * _local3)) {
            _local5[(_local6 % 4)][Math.floor((_local6 / 4))] = _arg1[_local6];
            _local6++;
        }
        ;
        _local5 = addRoundKey(_local5, _arg2, 0, _local3);
        var _local7 = 1;
        while (_local7 < _local4) {
            _local5 = subBytes(_local5, _local3);
            _local5 = shiftRows(_local5, _local3);
            _local5 = mixColumns(_local5);
            _local5 = addRoundKey(_local5, _arg2, _local7, _local3);
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        _local5 = subBytes(_local5, _local3);
        _local5 = shiftRows(_local5, _local3);
        _local5 = addRoundKey(_local5, _arg2, _local4, _local3);
        var _local8:Array = new Array((4 * _local3));
        var _local9:int;
        while (_local9 < (4 * _local3)) {
            _local8[_local9] = _local5[(_local9 % 4)][Math.floor((_local9 / 4))];
            _local9++;
        }
        ;
        return (_local8);
    }

    private static function keyExpansion(_arg1:Array):Array {
        var _local8:Array;
        var _local9:int;
        var _local2 = 4;
        var _local3:int = (_arg1.length / 4);
        var _local4:int = (_local3 + 6);
        var _local5:Array = new Array((_local2 * (_local4 + 1)));
        var _local6:Array = new Array(4);
        var _local7:int;
        while (_local7 < _local3) {
            _local8 = [_arg1[(4 * _local7)], _arg1[((4 * _local7) + 1)], _arg1[((4 * _local7) + 2)], _arg1[((4 * _local7) + 3)]];
            _local5[_local7] = _local8;
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        _local7 = _local3;
        while (_local7 < (_local2 * (_local4 + 1))) {
            _local5[_local7] = new Array(4);
            _local9 = 0;
            while (_local9 < 4) {
                _local6[_local9] = _local5[(_local7 - 1)][_local9];
                _local9++;
            }
            ;
            if ((_local7 % _local3) == 0) {
                _local6 = subWord(rotWord(_local6));
                _local9 = 0;
                while (_local9 < 4) {
                    _local6[_local9] = (_local6[_local9] ^ RCON[(_local7 / _local3)][_local9]);
                    _local9++;
                }
                ;
            } else {
                if ((((_local3 > 6)) && (((_local7 % _local3) == 4)))) {
                    _local6 = subWord(_local6);
                }
                ;
            }
            ;
            _local9 = 0;
            while (_local9 < 4) {
                _local5[_local7][_local9] = (_local5[(_local7 - _local3)][_local9] ^ _local6[_local9]);
                _local9++;
            }
            ;
            _local7++;
        }
        ;
        return (_local5);
    }

    private static function subBytes(_arg1:Array, _arg2:int):Array {
        var _local4:int;
        var _local3:int;
        while (_local3 < 4) {
            _local4 = 0;
            while (_local4 < _arg2) {
                _arg1[_local3][_local4] = SBOX[_arg1[_local3][_local4]];
                _local4++;
            }
            ;
            _local3++;
        }
        ;
        return (_arg1);
    }

    private static function shiftRows(_arg1:Array, _arg2:int):Array {
        var _local5:int;
        var _local3:Array = new Array(4);
        var _local4 = 1;
        while (_local4 < 4) {
            _local5 = 0;
            while (_local5 < 4) {
                _local3[_local5] = _arg1[_local4][((_local5 + _local4) % _arg2)];
                _local5++;
            }
            ;
            _local5 = 0;
            while (_local5 < 4) {
                _arg1[_local4][_local5] = _local3[_local5];
                _local5++;
            }
            ;
            _local4++;
        }
        ;
        return (_arg1);
    }

    private static function mixColumns(_arg1:Array):Array {
        var _local3:Array;
        var _local4:Array;
        var _local5:int;
        var _local2:int;
        while (_local2 < 4) {
            _local3 = new Array(4);
            _local4 = new Array(4);
            _local5 = 0;
            while (_local5 < 4) {
                _local3[_local5] = _arg1[_local5][_local2];
                _local4[_local5] = (((_arg1[_local5][_local2] & 128)) ? ((_arg1[_local5][_local2] << 1) ^ 283) : (_arg1[_local5][_local2] << 1));
                _local5++;
            }
            ;
            _arg1[0][_local2] = ((((_local4[0] ^ _local3[1]) ^ _local4[1]) ^ _local3[2]) ^ _local3[3]);
            _arg1[1][_local2] = ((((_local3[0] ^ _local4[1]) ^ _local3[2]) ^ _local4[2]) ^ _local3[3]);
            _arg1[2][_local2] = ((((_local3[0] ^ _local3[1]) ^ _local4[2]) ^ _local3[3]) ^ _local4[3]);
            _arg1[3][_local2] = ((((_local3[0] ^ _local4[0]) ^ _local3[1]) ^ _local3[2]) ^ _local4[3]);
            _local2++;
        }
        ;
        return (_arg1);
    }

    private static function addRoundKey(_arg1:Array, _arg2:Array, _arg3:int, _arg4:int):Array {
        var _local6:int;
        var _local5:int;
        while (_local5 < 4) {
            _local6 = 0;
            while (_local6 < _arg4) {
                _arg1[_local5][_local6] = (_arg1[_local5][_local6] ^ _arg2[((_arg3 * 4) + _local6)][_local5]);
                _local6++;
            }
            ;
            _local5++;
        }
        ;
        return (_arg1);
    }

    private static function subWord(_arg1:Array):Array {
        var _local2:int;
        while (_local2 < 4) {
            _arg1[_local2] = SBOX[_arg1[_local2]];
            _local2++;
        }
        ;
        return (_arg1);
    }

    private static function rotWord(_arg1:Array):Array {
        var _local2:int = _arg1[0];
        var _local3:int;
        while (_local3 < 3) {
            _arg1[_local3] = _arg1[(_local3 + 1)];
            _local3++;
        }
        ;
        _arg1[3] = _local2;
        return (_arg1);
    }

}
```

The above code is part of a flash tool I use in my app, now I need to replicate this in the server decrypting a URL that was encrypted by this AES algorithm, it's not password hacking(who uses aes for paswords and a known key) nor asking for a tool, it's understanding the AES implementation and reproduce the same behavior in PHP.
I tried `phpseclib` but I cannot produce the same output I get using the Actionscript code, I played with the lib but my output is always different. Following the previous example, in AS encrypting the text `hello world` with the key `my great key` I get `06/0/6Ojo6ObeIEZaHcxAinbjD==`, then in PHP I try something like:

```
$cipher = new Crypt_AES();
$cipher->setKeyLength(256);
$cipher->setKey('my great key');
echo base64_encode($cipher->encrypt('hello world'));
```

and it prints `v/Uc20nSNRNnJr0D15wBzA==`.

Comment: So either this is off topic because it's asking for a tool or library, or it's off topic because it is about hacking or password cracking, or both.

Answer (score 1):

To decode the base 64, you can use [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to decode the string into the raw bytes.  For decryption, this [library (phpseclib)](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html) seems to be ok.  They have examples on how to set up everything [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html).  It can optionally use mcrypt, but won't if you don't have it.